# Mongodb user table with friends

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a USER table with documents:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   name: 'funny-guy43',
   image: '../../../img1.jpg',
   friends: [2, 3]
},
{
   _id: 2,
   name: 'SurfinGirl3',
   image: '../../../img2.jpg',
   friends: []
},
{
   _id: 3,
   name: 'FooBarMan',
   image: '../../../img3.jpg',
   friends: [2]
}
```

friends is an array of USER _ids. (1) I want to get user by _id, (2) look at his friends and (3) query the USER table with the friend ids to return all friends.

for example, find user 1, query the table based on his friends 2 and 3, and return 2 and 3.

Can I do that in one transaction? Or do I query the table to get user array of friends, then query the table again with array of friends ids.

I'm using .Net Core if that matters.

I am very open to alternative approaches as well.

Comment: What is the expected output based on the JSON you are showing above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, in fact, possible to do this in one transaction. Or, to be more exact, in one aggregation.

I would first split the users into 2 different subsets, one called `searched_user` and the other `other_users`, where `searched_user` will have only the user we are searching for and `other_users` will have everyone else. We can do that using `$facet`. Here is the idea:

```
{
    "$facet": {
      "searched_user": [
        {
          $match: {
            _id: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "other_users": [
        {
          $match: {
            _id: {
              $ne: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Once they are separated like this, we can search the `other_users` subset using the friend ids from the `searched_user`. So here is the full aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "searched_user": [
        {
          $match: {
            _id: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "other_users": [
        {
          $match: {
            _id: {
              $ne: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$searched_user"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      user_friends: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$other_users",
          as: "other_users",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$other_users._id",
              "$searched_user.friends"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here we are looking for user 1 and the result will be user 1's friends.

```
[
  {
    "user_friends": [
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "friends": [],
        "image": "../../../img2.jpg",
        "name": "SurfinGirl3"
      },
      {
        "_id": 3,
        "friends": [
          2
        ],
        "image": "../../../img3.jpg",
        "name": "FooBarMan"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-8pNnQXg8r6

Comment: Why you make it extra complicated by using `$facet` and  `$unwind` ? while you could use `$lookup` ?, just wanting to understand if it's a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using lookup in aggregation, Tried it with MongoDB version v4.2.11.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            '_id': 1,
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from' : 'users',
            'let' : {
                'friendIds': '$friends', 
            },
            'pipeline': [
                {
                    '$match':{
                        '$expr': {'$in': [ '$_id', '$$friendIds']} 
                    }
                }
            ],
            'as': 'friendsArr'
        }
    }
])
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "funny-guy43",
        "image" : "../../../img1.jpg",
        "friends" : [
            2,
            3
        ],
        "friendsArr" : [
            {
                "_id" : 2,
                "name" : "SurfinGirl3",
                "image" : "../../../img2.jpg",
                "friends" : [ ]
            },
            {
                "_id" : 3,
                "name" : "FooBarMan",
                "image" : "../../../img3.jpg",
                "friends" : [
                    2
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```